# What drives the mass flow rate in axial turbofan between the compressor and the turbine when compressor is fully choked?

Tags: turbines, compressors, turbomachinery

I haven't found the answer in the forum or elsewhere, but maybe I have searched badly, in which case please forgive me in advance.
For a steady nominal operation of a turbofan, I have heard that the mass flow rate is driven by the sonic throat condition at the inlet of the high-pressure turbine.

However, I have also heard that if the mass flow rate is too high the compressor can be partially choked, and then eventually fully choked. But, correct me if I am wrong, if we are fully choked in the compressor, the mass flow rate will be fixed. **Therefore, what will happen for the sonic throat condition at high-pressure turbine ? Which one is going to fix the mass flow rate between the high-pressure turbine throat and the fully choked compressor ?**

Comment: What text books have you checked? There are many that cover compressible flow.

Comment: I have checked in my college lectures of Hillewaert on turbomachinery. But if you have advice on other relevant text books where I could find the answer, I am interested.